# How to find if a Scala String is parseable as a Double or not?

Tags: scala

Suppose that I have a string in scala and I want to try to parse a double out of it.

I know that, I can just call `toDouble` and then catch the java num format exception if this fails, but is there a cleaner way to do this?  For example if there was a `parseDouble` function that returned `Option[Double]` this would qualify.

I don't want to put this in my own code if it already exists in the standard library and I am just looking for it in the wrong place.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For Scala 2.13+ see Xavier's answer below. Apparently there's a `toDoubleOption` method now.

For older versions:

```
def parseDouble(s: String) = try { Some(s.toDouble) } catch { case _ => None }
```

---

Fancy version (edit: don't do this except for amusement value; I was a callow youth years ago when I used to write such monstrosities):

```
case class ParseOp[T](op: String => T)
implicit val popDouble = ParseOp[Double](_.toDouble)
implicit val popInt = ParseOp[Int](_.toInt)
// etc.
def parse[T: ParseOp](s: String) = try { Some(implicitly[ParseOp[T]].op(s)) } 
                                   catch {case _ => None}

scala> parse[Double]("1.23")
res13: Option[Double] = Some(1.23)

scala> parse[Int]("1.23")
res14: Option[Int] = None

scala> parse[Int]("1")
res15: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: You should really catch `NonFatal(_)`, not just `_`.

Comment: You should rather use the `Try` function. See @Jeff Schwab answer.

Comment: If you're using _Scala_ 2.13, you should use the direct method suggested in the answer by @XavierGuihot below: it does **exactly** what you want.

Answer (score 30):

Scalaz provides an extension method `parseDouble` on `String`s, which gives a value of type `Validation[NumberFormatException, Double]`.

```
scala> "34.5".parseDouble
res34: scalaz.Validation[NumberFormatException,Double] = Success(34.5)

scala> "34.bad".parseDouble
res35: scalaz.Validation[NumberFormatException,Double] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34.bad")
```

You can convert it to `Option` if so required.

```
scala> "34.bad".parseDouble.toOption
res36: Option[Double] = None
```

Comment: How does the performance of this compare to the default library implementation wrapped in a `Try()`?

Comment: @NightWolf, `Try` didn't exist at the time I wrote this answer. :-) In this context, both approaches work the same way, and the performance should be the same.

Comment: @NightWolf, I think Scalaz has since done away with `Validation` and introduced another type with similar but more sound properties. I could be wrong though. I haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 18):

```
scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> def parseDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = Try { s.toDouble }.toOption
parseDouble: (s: String)Option[Double]

scala> parseDouble("3.14")
res0: Option[Double] = Some(3.14)

scala> parseDouble("hello")
res1: Option[Double] = None
```

Answer (score 10):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toDoubleOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toDoubleOption:Option[Double]):

```
"5.7".toDoubleOption                // Option[Double] = Some(5.7)
"abc".toDoubleOption                // Option[Double] = None
"abc".toDoubleOption.getOrElse(-1d) // Double = -1.0
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer if you're using _Scala_ 2.13 or above!

Answer (score 9):

You could try using `util.control.Exception.catching` which returns an `Either` type.

So using the following returns a Left wrapping a `NumberFormatException` or a Right wrapping a `Double`

```
import util.control.Exception._

catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) either "12.W3".toDouble
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this isn't in the standard library.  Here's what I use:

```
class SafeParsePrimitive(s: String) {
  private def nfe[T](t: => T) = {
    try { Some(t) }
    catch { case nfe: NumberFormatException => None }
  }
  def booleanOption = s.toLowerCase match {
    case "yes" | "true" => Some(true)
    case "no" | "false" => Some(false)
    case _ => None
  }
  def byteOption = nfe(s.toByte)
  def doubleOption = nfe(s.toDouble)
  def floatOption = nfe(s.toFloat)
  def hexOption = nfe(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(s,16))
  def hexLongOption = nfe(java.lang.Long.valueOf(s,16))
  def intOption = nfe(s.toInt)
  def longOption = nfe(s.toLong)
  def shortOption = nfe(s.toShort)
}
implicit def string_parses_safely(s: String) = new SafeParsePrimitive(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing like this not only in Scala, but even in basic Java.

Here's a piece code that does it **without exceptions**, though:

```
def parseDouble(s: String)(implicit nf: NumberFormat) = {
    val pp = new ParsePosition(0)
    val d = nf.parse(s, pp)
    if (pp.getErrorIndex == -1) Some(d.doubleValue) else None
}
```

Usage:

```
implicit val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)

Console println parseDouble("184.33")
Console println parseDouble("hello, world")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually go with an "in place" Try:

```
def strTimesTen (s: String) = for (d <- Try(s.toDouble)) yield d * 10

strTimesTen("0.1") match {
    Success(d) => println( s"It is $d" )
    Failure(ex) => println( "I've asked for a number!" )
}
```

Note, that you can do further calculation in the for and any exception would project into a Failure(ex). AFAIK this is the idiomatic way of handling a sequence of unreliable operations.

Comment: I may be wrong as I'm v new to scala but I believe that to make this compile one has to a) import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure} and add the word 'case' before the words 'Success' and 'Failure'