# Scala: convert string to Int or None

Tags: scala, casting, scala-option

I am trying to get a number out of an xml field

```
...
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
...
```

via

```
Some((recipe \ "Main" \ "Quantity").text.toInt)
```

Sometimes there may not be a value in the xml, though.  The text will be `""` and this throws an java.lang.NumberFormatException.

What is a clean way to get either an Int or a None?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala is a string parseable as a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542126/scala-is-a-string-parseable-as-a-double)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> def tryToInt( s: String ) = Try(s.toInt).toOption
tryToInt: (s: String)Option[Int]

scala> tryToInt("123")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(123)

scala> tryToInt("")
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: If you are parsing a lot of empty strings, you might want to catch them explicitly instead of throwing an exception every time: `if (s.isEmpty) None else Try(s.toInt).toOption`.

Answer (score 32):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]):

```
"5".toIntOption                 // Option[Int] = Some(5)
"abc".toIntOption               // Option[Int] = None
"abc".toIntOption.getOrElse(-1) // Int = -1
```

Answer (score 11):

More of a side note on usage following accepted answer. After `import scala.util.Try`, consider

```
implicit class RichOptionConvert(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def toOptInt() = Try (s.toInt) toOption
}
```

or similarly but in a bit more elaborated form that addresses only the relevant exception in converting onto integral values, after `import java.lang.NumberFormatException`,

```
implicit class RichOptionConvert(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def toOptInt() = 
    try { 
      Some(s.toInt) 
    } catch { 
      case e: NumberFormatException => None 
    }
}
```

Thus,

```
"123".toOptInt
res: Option[Int] = Some(123)

Array(4,5,6).mkString.toOptInt
res: Option[Int] = Some(456)

"nan".toInt
res: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Shouldn't `"nan".toInt` be `"nan".toOptInt`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way of doing this that doesn't require writing your own function and which can also be used to lift to `Either`.

```
scala> import util.control.Exception._
import util.control.Exception._

scala> allCatch.opt { "42".toInt }
res0: Option[Int] = Some(42)

scala> allCatch.opt { "answer".toInt }
res1: Option[Int] = None

scala> allCatch.either { "42".toInt }
res3: scala.util.Either[Throwable,Int] = Right(42)
```

(A [nice blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-exception-allcatch-examples-option-try-either) on the subject.)

Comment: Your final example won't give that result.  Looks like a cut-n-paste error.

Comment: oops. thanks. only changed it because the left was annoyingly long.