# How to convert a var to Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, jenkins

Is there a method to convert a `var` to `Int` in Scala?

Suppose I have:

```
var noOfConcurrentUsers =  sys.env.get("NumberOfConcurrentUsers");

// I need the following
var userNo = noOfConcurrentUsers //some method
```

I am getting the variable as an environment variable in `String` format from `Jenkins`.

Getting error:

```
 Cannot resolve symbol toInt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: convert string to Int or None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811425/scala-convert-string-to-int-or-none)

Comment: @Dima Not a duplicate.

Comment: @downvoter Reason for downvote?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee the reason for downvote is your failure to figure out the type of your variable before rushing to SO with your question.
Also, it is a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correct, but if this conversion from Str to Int then:

```
var noOfConcurrentUsers = "10";

val i : Int = noOfConcurrentUsers.toInt
```

**EDIT**

What worked for me was:

```
var noOfConcurrentUsers =  sys.env.get("NumberOfConcurrentUsers"); 
var noOfUsers = noOfConcurrentUsers.toString().toInt
```

Let it be a final nail:)

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html

Comment: Actually I got the variable from Jenkins and had to convert it to String first. You have got the right answer. Marked it as accepted.

Comment: Correct way would be to use `Try(variable.toInt)`.

Comment: Yes, that a good point, are you sure you always will get string convertible to int?

Comment: @Reactormonk Yeah, I agree, will be a safer way to go. Still new to Scala, trying to get my head around it.

Comment: @Pavel Yes, getting the variable as String and asking the user to enter only number.