# How to convert Any number to Double?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I need to do some raw data parsing and I am forced to work with `Any` type.

If the data I read is in any numeric format (`Int`/`Double`/`Long`/...) I need to convert it to `Double`, otherwise (eg. `String`) I need to leave it empty.

This is what I came up with:

```
def extractDouble(expectedNumber: Any): Option[Double] = expectedNumber match {
  case i: Int => Some(i.toDouble)
  case l: Long => Some(l.toDouble)
  case d: Double => Some(d)
  case _ => None
}
```

This obviously doesn't look even decently. Is there any better way to deal with this in Scala?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you lost your type information at compile time, as it happens to be in your case since your input type is `Any` as part of its requirements, there is no more options than inspecting `expectedNumber` at run time with `isInstanceOf`.

That is masked by the implementation of type pattern matching you are doing in your proposed solution. And I think that is the best solution in your case.

However, there is an alternative which is using `Try` over  and transforming it into an `Option`. e.g:

```
Try(expectedNumber.toString.toDouble).toOption
```

That's a dirty solution in so many ways (not efficient at all, using exceptions to control flow, ...) that **I would definetively use your first approach**

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly possible, as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757213/5236247) answer:

Use `java.lang.Number` to match with your case type.

```scala
def extractDouble(x: Any): Option[Double] = x match {
  case n: java.lang.Number => Some(n.doubleValue())
  case _ => None
}
```

Note that this also works for instances of `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`, be it `scala.math.BigDecimal` or `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the OP's solution for a while. But upon encountering some slightly corrupted data input, I subsequently changed to a combination of OP's solution and the `Try` solution.

```
  def extractDouble(expectedNumber: Any): Option[Double] = expectedNumber match {
    case i: Int => Some(i.toDouble)
    case l: Long => Some(l.toDouble)
    case d: Double => Some(d)
    case s: String => Try(s.trim.toDouble).toOption
    case _ => None
  }
```

the `case s:String` line may save you a bit of debugging and head scratching down the line if you are dealing with big and potentially messy data

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, we could apply the new [`String::toDoubleOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toDoubleOption:Option[Double]) after transforming `expectedNumber: Any` to `String`:

```
def extractDouble(expectedNumber: Any): Option[Double] =
  expectedNumber.toString.toDoubleOption
```

For instance:

```
extractDouble(12.56d)  // Option[Double] = Some(12.56)
extractDouble(12)      // Option[Double] = Some(12.0)
extractDouble(12L)     // Option[Double] = Some(12.0)
extractDouble("hello") // Option[Double] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.util.Try    
def parseDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = Try { s.toDouble }.toOption
```

[Scala is a string parseable as a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542126/scala-is-a-string-parseable-as-a-double)

Comment: -1 This does not, or just in part, answer OPs question. They said that they are forced to use the `Any` parameter, and also only works if you have a `String` (which is of course easily achieved, but digresses from the original problem).

Comment: That is good point...the parseDouble can be modified as def parseDouble(s: Any): Option[Double] = Try { s..toString.toDouble }.toOption

Comment: But then, it's roughly the same as Pablo but without the warnings of why it is a bad idea.

Comment: Fully agree that is an extension of Palbo...I just wanted to share the link that has some examples if that helps.